# ffmpeg exported file is broken

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using using ffmpeg to trim and join several audio files. The ouput audio file can be played as a normal file, but when I open it in some C# codes, exceptions are always throwing, says "`MP3 Header is missing`". I am new to ffmpeg and I googled for many times but seems no one is encountering this problem.

Here is my ffmpeg command to trim an audio file:

```
ffmpeg -i input_1.mp3 -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:01.000 -acodec libmp3lame 1.mp3
```

(The input audio format can be mp3/wma/wav/m4a/aac)

And the following is for joining all the audio files:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -acodec libmp3lame join.mp3
```

The `list.txt` contents:

```
file C:\\1.mp3
file C:\\2.mp3
file C:\\3.mp3
```

Comment: Make sure all converted files have same sampling rate and channel count i.e. add `-ar 44100 -ac 2`

Comment: Thank you Gyan! Your parameters did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem soved! Thanks to [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan)'s comment under my question.
The main point:

> Make sure all converted files have same sampling rate and channel count i.e. add `-ar 44100 -ac 2`

The above parameters did solve my problem.